# precise 50 Hz oscillator

Tags: frequency, duty-cycle, multivibrator, astable, tolerance

I need an astable multi-vibrator at **exactly** 50 or 100 Hz with exactly 50% duty cycle.
using circuits like 555 can't give me that with the common well-known values of components R and C , let alone the tolerance of components .

so , any suggestions ??

thanks

Comment: You can't have exactly 50 Hz, but you can get arbitrarily close if you're willing to spend arbitrarily large amounts of money.  How close do you need?

Comment: The closest you can practically get would involve getting a caesium reference standard and deriving your clock from that. That will set you back several hundred thousand dollars.

Comment: Crystal oscillator, clock divider? Still won't be exact but you can get quite close.

Comment: are you telling me that exact 50Hz with exact 50% duty cycle is near impossible ?

Comment: @AbdAlhaleemBakkor Yes, *exactly* is impossible. *Almost* exact, for example to an accuracy of 0.005%, is possible. Come up with a numerical spec.

Comment: @AbdAlhaleemBakkor First, we've no idea what exists after the output you hope to have. What's the path and its parasitics and what's the load and its parasitics? And how is the analog result, rising and falling, interpreted at the receiving end? Second, getting closer than 32 seconds drift per year means staying underneath 1 ppm. And that's just precision, which has little to do with accuracy. Accuracy requires calibration against agreed-upon standards (only a few in the world exist), or against instrumentation whose provenances can prove some known traceability back to those same standards.

Comment: @AbdAlhaleemBakkor You may need to place within your system control everything from temperature, entropy, noise, short and long term drifts, vibrations, and even the Earth's gravitational time dilation (which varies in some tricky fashion with altitude and surroundings.) This means tracking down and removing as much residual heteroscedasticity as possible. It can take a very long time to gain and then retain any arbitrary sufficient confidence, if you are looking for high accuracy results.

Comment: @AbdAlhaleemBakkor Not near impossible, literally impossible.

Comment: @AbdAlhaleemBakkor If you're not able to calculate how much accuracy you need, it would be better to describe your underlying problem and then ask for help solving it directly.

Comment: What does the GPS network use for its reference? If its the underlying network of national standards defining time, then exactly is possible, by definition, on average, by using a GPS disciplined reference. If it's only the US portion of it, then it will only be close, That close will be closer though than an amateur would ever be able to measure or demonstrate.

Comment: Why 50 Hz? Sounds suspiciously like mains frequency to me. Do you want to track the mains? While it has instantaneous errors of typically no more than 0.1 Hz, it can be 0.5 Hz out in exceptional circumstances, but is corrected so that over the course of 24 hours, the average daily frequency is exactly 50 Hz, at least in the UK and Europe. If you want to reference an AC power supply, then +/- 1% is good enough for standalone use, Exact is not good enough for injection use because of the inherent grid variability, you must track it.

Comment: "Exactly" is not a technical term. Nothing is exact in this world. It all depends how accurate you measure the quantity. So be specific on how much error you expect maximum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exact is not possible. How precise does your oscillator need to be and how much jitter can you withstand? What is your budget? Since you're mentioning a 555 timer, I'm assuming that spending over €1000 is not desirable.

Some inexpensive options:
You can use a temperature compensated crystal oscillator (**TCXO**) and get 1 or 2 ppm accuracy for under €5 up to a very fancy meal at a 5 star eatery. TCXOs do drift, perhaps no more than 1ppm per year, so you may want an adjustable TCXO if accuracy is important. However, you'll need an accurate source to calibrate the oscillator.

If you need good precision at low cost, you can buy **GPS based timing systems** that have a disciplined oscillator, often a 10MHz output with 0.001 ppm accuracy. It usually takes a couple minutes for the oscillator to reach specified accuracy after satellite lock. If you do an Internet search, you can find kits for perhaps €100.

Divide the output frequency down to 100Hz, then use a flip-flop to give you a 50% duty cycle at 50Hz.

Comment: +1 for GPS based idea. It is probably useless for OP but might come in handy for someone with tight requirements.

Comment: Thank you all for your time and effort, I had a lot of good ideas and information from your answers . Though there was no reason for all the negativity and down votes , I’m asking about an exact principle and the circuit following the signal has nothing to do with the answer to my question , you could have considered it for scientific purposes and just answer it.

Comment: @AbdAlhaleemBakkor If you want to read up on how the exact second is derived, see [The International System of Units](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/pdf/si-brochure/SI-Brochure-9.pdf) (in French & English). Unfortunately, to generate an exact frequency is not possible without having a specialized laboratory. Even then, there is a problem with jitter which causes short time issues. Do not construe the comments as negative. They are only trying to impress that exact frequency generation is not possible. We can only state that the frequency is within an error band.